# What's the difference between Stubs and Fakes?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

Sinon.js provides [Fakes](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.1/fakes/). But I didn't see any essential differences with [Stubs](https://sinonjs.org/releases/v9.0.1/stubs/). Here is example code under test:

`index.ts`:

```js
export function main(callback) {
  return callback();
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import sinon from 'sinon';
import { main } from './';

describe('sinon fake vs stub', () => {
  it('should pass when using a sinon stub', () => {
    const callback = sinon.stub().returns('value');
    const actual = main(callback);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'value');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(callback);
  });

  it('should pass when using a sinon fake', () => {
    const callback = sinon.fake.returns('value');
    const actual = main(callback);
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'value');
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(callback);
  });
});
```

test results:

```sh
  sinon fake vs stub
    ✓ should pass when using a sinon stub
    ✓ should pass when using a sinon fake


  2 passing (9ms)
```

For `sinon.fake.throws(value);`, `sinon.fake.resolves(value);`, `sinon.fake.yields([value1, ..., valueN]);` APIs and so on. I can also use `sinon.stubs()` do these.

I use `sinon.stubs()` a lot, the documentation of `Fakes` doesn't give special scenes can only use fakes. I can currently test all scenarios using `sinon.stubs()`.

Comment: The documentation does say "*Unlike `sinon.spy` and `sinon.stub` methods, the `sinon.fake` API knows only how to create fakes, and doesn’t concern itself with plugging them into the system under test*" so, it seems the fakes are *only* fake implementations of functions, while stubs also includes the option to actually add them to other objects. Not sure if that's entirely correct but that's the sense I got from looking at the doc. I will not be surprised if stubs actually uses fakes under the hood.